# XSLT producing HTML using Java API's

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a specific requirement where I have to 
develop XSLT scripts that produce HTML files for the output of each of the SQL queries (or sets of queries) using `javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet.writeXml(ResultSet rs, OutputStream oStream)`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't see any XSLT in the `WebRowSet` pipeline. Is this what this question is about? If so, I fear you might have to write to a `StringWriter` or `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then read the data from there to apply your XSLT using `java.xml.transform` and a stylesheet with the [HTML output method](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method) selected.

Answer (score 0):

Give writeXml a ByteArrayOutputStream to write to, and then supply this wrapped in a StreamSource as input to the transformation.

If you want to avoid allocating memory for the XML and to stream it directly, then you could achieve that using two threads, but it would be more complicated.